# Is there a closed form for the sequence $1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 10, 12, 4, 8, 18, 6, 11, ... $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

This sequence is generated from: the least $m>0$ such that $2n+1 |2^m-1$

I was wondering if there was a way to express it in a closed from $f(2n+1)$?

More terms include: $1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 10, 12, 4, 8, 18, 6, 11, 20, 18, 28, 5, 10, 12, 36, 12, 20, 14, 12, 23, 21, ...$

With the full list on:
https://oeis.org/A002326

Comment: Probably no,because answer would be on the site `OEIS`

Comment: So , the sequence basically contains the orders of $2$ modulo the odd numbers. Does $ord_2(2n+1)$ count as a closed form ?

Comment: Peter, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the "order of 2" part of the modulo form. Can you explain that, or is there a link for this form. I've never seen this form before. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a copy of the book so I can't post a definitive answer, but I feel like the answer must be "no", given that the OEIS page says "Concerning the complexity of computing this sequence, see for example Bach and Shallit, p. 115, exercise 8.". If it has interesting complexity then theres not likely a simple formula.

Comment: @Joseph wikipedia uses the reverse convention compared to Peter, but you can read about multiplicative order at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks for the link! I was having trouble finding it. I guess the multiplicative order is as close to a closed form as I can get. I'll try working with it. Thank you again!